# image loading into DynamoDB using: PHP, Ubuntu, EC2 Amazon Web Services

Tags: php, html, linux, image, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying trying to load an image provided trough an HTML form into a Dynamo Db table.

I'm hard coding the image loading part, but later I want to uncomment:

```
$con=file_get_contents( basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]) );
```

And upload any image into DynamoDB.

This is the html file:

```
<form action="upload-download-dynamodb.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the upload-download-dynamodb.php

```
<?php

// Convert image to binary 

    //$con=file_get_contents( basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]) ); 

            $con=file_get_contents("Tuan.jpg");
                        $en=base64_encode($con);
                        $mime='image/gif';
                        $binary_data='data:' . $mime . ';base64,' . $en ;

?>
                  <img src="<?php echo $binary_data; ?>" alt="Test">
<?php

//  Connect to Dynamodb 

require './awssdkphp/aws-autoloader.php';
use Aws\DynamoDb\DynamoDbClient;

$client = DynamoDbClient::factory(array(
    'profile' => 'default',
    'region' => 'us-east-1'  // replace with your desired region
));

//  Put item inside a table 

$responsePut = $client->putItem(array(
    'TableName' => 'saleItems', 
    'Item' => array(
         'itemID'  => array('N' => 11 ), // Primary  
         'picture' => array('B' => openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(5)), 
         'array' => array('S' =>  $en),
         'description' => array ('S' => "picture description"  )
                   )

));

?>
```

The  "upload-download-dynamodb.php" code works fine if I run it in the terminal(e.i.  php upload-download-dynamodb.php). Buy if I execute the "upload-download-dynamodb.php on the browser(Firefox), the image is displayed but the data is not uploaded into the 'saleItems' table in Dynamo DB.

Any ideas of why the "upload-download-dynamodb.php" code loads the picture into Dynamo DB when I execute it through the terminal but not when I execute it in the browser(Clicking the refresh button)?

BTW, I gave full permissions to upload-download-dynamodb.html ,upload-download-dynamodb.php and Tuan.jpg.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally figured out what was going on.

I had my credentials as environmental variables in the terminal. For some reason, PHP couldn't access those credentials when I executed the upload-download-dynamodb.php through the html file.

I hard coded the credentials to the upload-download-dynamodb.php file by adding the following lines of code:

```
use Aws\Common\Credentials\Credentials;

$credentials = new Credentials('YOUR_ACCESS_KEY','YOUR_SECRET_KEY');

$client = DynamoDbClient::factory(array(
    'profile' => 'default',
    'region' => 'us-east-1',  // replace with your desired region
    'credentials' => $credentials
));
```

Now the code works fine.